# How do you use a firefox plugin within a selenium webdriver program written in java?

Tags: java, firefox-addon, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to run a selenium script that clicks on one of my firefox plugins in my toolbar. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Ok, well i figured that this is not possible. A better question might be is there another tool that can automate this?

Comment: This thread might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975184/test-automation-tool-libraries-framework-for-c-gui-desktop-windows-apps

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can't click on the element since it's not a web page element.  However you can create a profile for firefox and include addons in that profile that is launched by the webdriver applications.  This will allow you to have access to Firebug or other addons.  I'm not sure of the interaction between the addons myself since I don't use this but the way you set a profile and extend the profile with the addon api is like so:

```
File file = new File("firebug-1.8.1.xpi");
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
firefoxProfile.addExtension(file);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.8.1"); // Avoid startup screen
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

Referenced - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Comment: Actually it's very tricky. Selenium does not work well with Firefox. I tried with latest 3.0 stable version and it didn't work. Then I tried 3.0 beta version and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

You can automate the above scenario by using an automation tool called "Autoit".
We just need to write a small script for clicking on the respective co-ordinates with the help of this tool.
You can refer: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/