# Selenium Firefox driver with Firefox plugins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Is it possible to use selenium Firefox driver with plugins installed in Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a firefox plugin within a selenium webdriver program written in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a firefox profile to add addons to your tests. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j) stackoverflow post for an example.