# Selenium webdriver & hola.org addon

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use hola.org addon with Selenium & firefox webdriver.

For the moment I have the firefox browser with the addon installed, however I don't know how to start the addon and how to choose a location to emulate.

Probably I have to set some profile preferences... I've took a look into the add folder looking for the proper configuration.... but I didn't see anything.

Any idea? Anyone did it?

Comment: I am not sure you can interact with an addon through selenium webdriver as it is not part of the webpage. You can add it to a browser that webdriver opens. Refer to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j

Comment: Yes, I already add it to the browser and I know that there is no way to interact from the webdriver. My idea was to add some info to the firefox profile (or to the addon config) in order to make the addon available when I start webdriver with that profile.