# How do I handle allow pop-up of plug-in for firefox using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium

While automating the web page which includes Vidyo Web player plugin.
If I am navigating to the Video page, the allow pop-up is showing.
I have tried to with the below code to handle allow pop-up. But it's not working.

Below is the code which am using,

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("security.mixed_content.block_active_content", true);
profile.setPreference("security.mixed_content.block_display_content", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

[image]

Can any one help on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to hide this pop-up or to allow using plug-in automatically or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j) answer, you probably need to source the file for the extension and use the below:

```
File file = new File("path to extension file");    
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.addExtension(file);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this preference:

```
FirefoxProfile profile= new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference(“browser.popups.showPopupBlocker”, false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this preference to get rid of "Allow"/"Continue Blocking":

```
profile.setPreference("plugin.scan.plid.all", false);
```

Also you might need to use this to automatically allow extension

```
profile.setPreference("extensions.blocklist.enabled", false);
```