# Java Selenium - Testing unsigned extensions

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, automated-tests

I am trying to automate extension testing using Java and selenium. Unfortunately, unsigned extensions get removed after each session. Is there a way I can keep my unsigned extension installed on the firefox profile I choose?

Is there a better way to go about this? As far as I've searched, the nightly firefox build can do this but is not supported by selenium.

Comment: I may resort to automate the installation of the extension before testing.

Comment: You should be able to programmatically create a firefox profile and part of that process can include adding addons.  Maybe this answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

Comment: couldn't get it to work

Comment: Update your question with what you tried and what specifically about the thing you tried that didn't work