# Setting Cookies without visiting a page in Selenum

Tags: java, selenium, cookies, geckodriver

Anyone able to explain to me how I would be able to set cookies for a domain not visited with the use of a plugin with selenium for gecko driver? I have been trying to set a cookie to prevent seeing a login page, but the domain for the cookie is redirecting so I cannot set it by visiting it and cannot figure out how to do it.

I have tried this but looks as though I cannot specify this in selenium as I cannot visit this page.

```
Cookie cookie11 = new Cookie("SID",
                  "cookievalue",
                  ".google.com",
                  "/",
                  expiry1,
                  false,
                  false);
```

Found a plugin called Cookies Export/import that I am trying to figure out if its possible to use to import the cookies from..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Same question for Python: [How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver) -- most methods there should work as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use the specified extension in order to do this, I recommend looking at the SO Answer on [How do you use a firefox plugin within a selenium webdriver program written in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070867/how-do-you-use-a-firefox-plugin-within-a-selenium-webdriver-program-written-in-j) and you should be good from there.

However, I believe you can achieve this without using an extension, using `addCookie()` method.

```java
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("SID",
              "cookievalue",
              ".example.com",
              "/",
              expiry1,
              false,
              false); 

driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
driver.get("http://www.example.com/login");
```

Assuming your cookie details are correct, you should be able to get past the login redirect.

See also: 
[WebDriver – How to Restore Cookies in New Browser Window](https://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-how-to-restore-cookies-in-new-browser-window/)

Comment: I've been across that link before, and it only shows how to load and specify the version, can't seem to find anything on how I might trigger an action within a plugin. 

The cookies I need to set are on .google and mail.google.com  so by the time i visit them either has timed out or have forwarded. And from what I have been able to find all cookies must be set from the actual page so not sure if this will work.. I have tried with no avail

Comment: Unfortunately, setting cookies like this causes exception `org.openqa.selenium.InvalidCookieDomainException: Document is cookie-averse`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that. See https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#add-cookie

I opened this issue with the spec https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1238

You need to rebuild the browser without those validations if you want to get passed this issue:

Here is the changes to make to FireFox (marionette) to get passed this:
https://gist.github.com/nddipiazza/1c8cc5ec8dd804f735f772c038483401